# Is that true that every time the user connect the db, I need to create a connection?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I see many tutorial about connection db is open a connection, and do the stuff, and close the connection in the end. I would like to know whether this is true for real life example?
I know it can get the job done when I open, and close the connection every time. But will it have some performance issue? Moreover, can I reuse the opened connection? Or is this inevitable to keep open and closing the db?? Thanks.

*I am using php + mysql, thanks.

Comment: Performance issues depend entirely on your application, your hardware, and your audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mysql_pconnect` if you want a persistent connection:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Though, in my experience, I don't like this.  If you're running your database and webserver on the same host, then the time to set up a connection is very VERY small.  I initialize a connection for every visitor with minimal cost.

If the mysql database is remote relative to your website, you might want to consider this.  Setting up a connection takes multiple round trips.  So if you ping WEBSERVER to MYSQLSERVER and it's 100ms.  It's going to take multiple times that to get a connection.  In this case, it might be worth using a persistent connection.

Comment: It also depends on the number of queries and how often you query. If you are running multiple queries every second per user, a persistent connection is something you want to take a look at.